# How to refactor each function with map in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a loop building a hash for use in a select field.  The intention is to end up with a hash:

```
{ object.id => "object name", object.id => "object name" }
```

Using:

```
@hash = {}
loop_over.each do |ac|
  @hash[ac.name] = ac.id
end
```

I think that the `map` method is meant for this type of situation but just need some help understanding it and how it works.  Is `map` the right method to refactor this `each` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data transformations like this are better suited to [`each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
@hash = loop_over.each_with_object({}) { |ac, h| h[ac.name] = ac.id }
```

If your brain is telling you to use `map` but you don't want an array as the result, then you usually want to use `each_with_object`. If you want to feed the block's return value back into itself, then you want [`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) but in cases like this, `inject` requires a funny looking and artificial `;h` in the block:

```
@hash = loop_over.inject({}) { |h, ac| h[ac.name] = ac.id; h }
# -------------------- yuck -----------------------------^^^
```

The presence of the artificial return value is the signal that you want to use `each_with_object` instead.

Comment: You always arrive as the savior, with a clear, short and perfect answer. I admire you somehow!

Comment: Your `inject` syntax needs correction. the injected parameter is the first argument in the block arguments list than last.

Comment: @kiddorails: Thanks, fixed. I usually remember that `inject` args are in the opposite order as `each_with_object` and the `each_with_object` order matches the name.

Comment: @MrYoshiji That's because I've been around long to have made all the usual mistakes over and over again :)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
Hash[loop_over.map { |ac| [ac[:name], ac[:id]] }]
```

Or if you are running on Ruby 2:

```
loop_over.map { |ac| [ac[:name], ac[:id]] }.to_h
```

Comment: +1 In Ruby 2, I prefer `map` over `each_with_object` for cases like this (I don't care for the `Hash[]` idiom)

Answer (score 1):

```
@hash = Hash[loop_over.map { |ac| {ac.name => ac.id} }.map(&:flatten)]
```

Edit, a simpler solution as per suggestion in a comment.

```
@hash = Hash[ loop_over.map { |ac| [ac.name, ac.id] } ]
```

Comment: That's an array of hashes.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah I realized that, fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can *simply* do this by injecting a blank new `Hash` and performing your operation:

```
loop_over.inject({}){ |h, ac| h[ac.name] = ac.id; h }
```

**Ruby FTW**

Answer (score 0):

No a map isn't the correct tool for this.

The general use-case of a `map` is to take in an array, perform an operation on each element, and spit out a (possibly) new array (*not* a hashmap) of the same length, with the individual element modifications.

Here's an example of a map

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4].map do |i|
  i+1 #transform each element by adding 1
end

p x # will print out [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Your code:

```
@hash = {}
loop_over.each do |ac|
  @hash[ac.name] = ac.id
end
```

There is nothing wrong with this example. You are iterating over a list, and populating a hashmap exactly as you wished.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 2.1.0 introduces brand new method to generate hashes:

```
h = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
h.map { |k, v| [k, v+1] }.to_h # => {:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>4}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the `inject` version, but use `update` in the block to avoid the easy to miss (and therefore error prone) `;h` suffix:

```
@hash = loop_over.inject({}) { |h, ac| h.update(ac.name: ac.id) }
```